# Absorption of Beta decay and characteristic exponential absorption law

Tags: radiation, absorption

It has been discovered that Beta decays are a continuous spectrum of electrons and its absorption follows an exponential law with thickness of material (eg. Aluminium). This observation was often quoted, but has not been really explained in textbook. Where does this exponential law come from, or is it an empirical observation that is only partly true?

Comment: This is a natural mathematical consequence of having an interaction possibility (absorption or scattering out of the beam) that depends only on the amount of material the beam passes by (thickness for uniform density, number of atoms, etc.).

Comment: What Jon said. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attenuation_coefficient & the linked articles on attenuation & attenuation length.